# How to write the fucntion that transfrom the columns of my dataframe to a single column?

Tags: python, pandas, function, dataframe, lambda

I have a dataframe like this:

```
A =   ID Material1 Materia2 Material3 
      14   0        0        0
      24   1        0        0 
      12   1        1        0
      25   0        0        2
```

I want to have all information in one column like this:

```
A =   ID  Materials
      14   Nan 
      24   Material1
      12   Material1 
      12   Material2
      25   Material3 
      25   Material3
```

can anyone help write a function please !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) with repeat rows by counts with [`Index.repeat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.repeat.html) and [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df1 = df.melt('ID', var_name='Materials')
df1 = df1.loc[df1.index.repeat(df1['value'])].drop('value', axis=1).reset_index(drop=True)
print (df1)
   ID  Materials
0  24  Material1
1  12  Material1
2  12   Materia2
3  25  Material3
4  25  Material3
```

EDIT: For add only `0` Materials with missing values use [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with left join by original `df['ID']` in one column DataFrame withoiut duplications by [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
df1 = df.melt('ID', var_name='Materials')

df0 = df[['ID']].drop_duplicates()
print (df0)
   ID
0  14
1  24
2  12
3  25

df2 = df1.loc[df1.index.repeat(df1['value'])].drop('value', axis=1).reset_index(drop=True)

df2 = df0.merge(df2, on='ID', how='left')
print (df2)
   ID  Materials
0  14        NaN
1  24  Material1
2  12  Material1
3  12   Materia2
4  25  Material3
5  25  Material3
```

Comment: It worked fine , but how can i save the lines that have no materials , cauz now i only have ID with at least one material ? i Just edited my question